# libGDX, detect side touching between rectangles (side collision)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I use libGDX library for my game. I user `overlap` method for detecting collision detection between two rectangles.

```
...
if (r1.overlaps(r2)) collisionTest();
...
```

I want to detect touching side on rectangle (top, bottom, left or right):

```
r1 overlap r2 on the left side
```

Can anyone give me code for this, but this need to be fast method.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the method `intersectRectangles` provided in the `Intersector` class to determine if two rectangles are overlapping, and if so, where they overlap. You could use this info to determine if they overlap with the left, right, top, and/or bottom.

```
Rectangle r1 = /*Initialize*/;                             
Rectangle r2 = /*Initialize*/;                             
Rectangle intersection = new Rectangle();                  
Intersector.intersectRectangles(r1, r2, intersection);     
if(intersection.x > r1.x)                                  
    //Intersects with right side                              
if(intersection.y > r1.y)                                  
    //Intersects with top side                                
if(intersection.x + intersection.width < r1.x + r1.width)  
    //Intersects with left side                               
if(intersection.y + intersection.height < r1.y + r1.height)
    //Intersects with bottom side
```